# Problems in my sample C code using FFmpeg API

Tags: c++, c, pointers, video, ffmpeg

I've been trying to change an FFmpeg's example code [HERE](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/filtering_video.c) to call **other** filters using its C APIs. Say the filter be `freezedetect=n=-60dB:d=8` which normally runs like this:

```
ffmpeg -i small.mp4 -vf "freezedetect=n=-60dB:d=8" -map 0:v:0 -f null -
```

And prints outputs like this:

```
[freezedetect @ 0x25b91c0] lavfi.freezedetect.freeze_start: 5.005
[freezedetect @ 0x25b91c0] lavfi.freezedetect.freeze_duration: 2.03537
[freezedetect @ 0x25b91c0] lavfi.freezedetect.freeze_end: 7.04037
```

However, the original example displays frames, not these metadata information. How can I change the code to print this metadata information (and not the frames)?

I've been trying to change the `display_frame` function below into a `display_metadata` function. Looks like the `frame` variable has a `metadata` dictionary which looks promising, but my attempts failed to use it. I'm also new to C language.

Original `display_frame` function:

```
static void display_frame(const AVFrame *frame, AVRational time_base)
{
    int x, y;
    uint8_t *p0, *p;
    int64_t delay;

    if (frame->pts != AV_NOPTS_VALUE) {
        if (last_pts != AV_NOPTS_VALUE) {
            /* sleep roughly the right amount of time;
             * usleep is in microseconds, just like AV_TIME_BASE. */
            delay = av_rescale_q(frame->pts - last_pts,
                                 time_base, AV_TIME_BASE_Q);
            if (delay > 0 && delay < 1000000)
                usleep(delay);
        }
        last_pts = frame->pts;
    }

    /* Trivial ASCII grayscale display. */
    p0 = frame->data[0];
    puts("\033c");
    for (y = 0; y < frame->height; y++) {
        p = p0;
        for (x = 0; x < frame->width; x++)
            putchar(" .-+#"[*(p++) / 52]);
        putchar('\n');
        p0 += frame->linesize[0];
    }
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

My new `display_metadata` function that needs to be completed:

```
static void display_metadata(const AVFrame *frame)
{

//    printf("%d\n",frame->height);

    AVDictionary* dic = frame->metadata;

    printf("%d\n",*(dic->count));

//    fflush(stdout);
}
```

Comment: See metadata.c example.

Comment: @Gyan Thanks. Yes `av_dict_get(frame->metadata, "myfreezekey", tag, 0)` was a life saver! But I see the filter metadata `[freezedetect @ 0x25b91c0] lavfi.freezedetect.freeze_start: 5.005` is also printed by default! Any ways to disable that?

Comment: No, that's supplied by the filter and formatted by av_log

Comment: @Gyan Got it. It's weird. I remove `av_log` in the `set_meta` function of the filter C file. And make. But still see the same logs printed. Shouldn't it work?